# .NetStandard 2.0 can not be referenced by a project that targets xamarin.ios Version 1.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, .net-standard-2.0

i am trying to upgrade Xamarin.Forms project to .Net Standard 2.0 in Xamarin.iOS. so far its running fine in xamarin.android but when we complie it in 
iOS its throwing following error at complie time in Visual Studio 2017 community edition on mac machine.

[image]

[image]
we have tried clearing the obj and bin folder and our project is using all the lastest xamarin.forms library.

Moreover , xamarin forms project file already has following entry

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: And you are running latest stable version of Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: Yes running latest version

Comment: and over a mac machine

Comment: Add .NETStandard 2.0 NuGet to the iOS Project and try to rebuild again, Detail Steps:https://github.com/abock/bxc57842-repro-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring a lot i came across following link that converts pcl project to .Net standard and that worked for me.

[Blog link that explains the brief about Mutatio  plugin](https://smellyc0de.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/automatically-converting-pcl-to-net-standard-2-0-project/)

[Github link where in author has explained how to install Mutatio plugin in VS 2017 for Mac](https://github.com/yuv4ik/Mutatio)